# Can we use Present perfect+past participle to express finished habit?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-constructions

It has been 18 months since I worn the ring. (Does she still wear the ring or not? How to express she is still wearing it?)

Comment: The sentence means that she has **not** worn the ring for 18 months (assuming the sentence is supposed to read *wore* instead of *worn*, which is ungrammatical). *I've been wearing the ring for 18 months* is how I'd say that I've been wearing it for 18 months (and still am).

Comment: It has been 18 months since ***I have worn the ring***. In fact, wore would be ungrammatical here. Your question title says "to express finished habit** and you statement says **s still wearing it**: which one is it?

Comment: I wanted to know the variants. To confirm if the sentence is correctly expressing habit finished 18 months ago. And I also wanted to know, how to express she has been wearing it starting 18 months ago (for 18 months) using the word "since". To emphasise that it is since 18 month ago...? Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

***I have been wearing the ring for 18 months.***

The sentences above answers your question as to how to express that she is still wearing the ring.

***It has been 18 months since I started wearing this ring*** could be an option too. Mind that the sentence "It has been 18 months since I worn the ring" is incorrect. First of all, *worn* is the past participle (the Past Simple form is wore). But "...since she wore the ring" wouldn't be correct either. She's still wearing it. You need a verb that would mean the action which is in the past. For example, "start".